# How do I sweep one sketch along another in FreeCAD?

Tags: cad

I'm new to FreeCAD, I want to sweep one sketch along another. Here I want to sweep the rectangle sketch along the curvy path.

[image: Sketches]

But it ends up like this when I use Additive Pipe:

[image: Result]

What setting am I missing, or what am I doing wrong? Or is there a different way of accomplishing this? Any help or tips are welcome.

Comment: what is wrong with the result?

Comment: It should be two hoops connected by a line - all the same thickness.

Comment: so, it should look like bent metal rod? ... is the bottom picture partly correct?

Comment: maybe the rectangle should be a box

Comment: You should draw an image of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

place the rectangle so that it is centered on the point that starts the curve, then use additive pipe to sweep along the curve.